# jquery removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove all classes of an element that are not equal to a certain string,

for example, if I have the following HTML

```
<a href="" class="status pending"></a>
<a href="" class="status successful"></a>
<a href="" class="status unsuccessful"></a>
```

Could I remove all the classes that are not equal to status?

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
removeClass().addClass('status')
```

<s>Another option:</s>

```
removeClass(function(i, c) { return c.replace('status', ''); });
```

Answer (score 5):

or a bit faster

`$('.status').attr('class','status');`

will overwrite the class attribute of every element to hold only the 'status' value

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('a').hasClass("status")) {
   $('a').removeClass().addClass("status") 
} else {
   $('a').removeClass()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the status class to remain on all links you could do:

> $("a").attr("class", "status");